# Communication Between Components Child and Other Child

Tags: reactjs

I'm a new for ReactJS.

I would like to ask a simple question for you.

How can i update other child when the child has been changed?

Thanks!

.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYuaP.jpg)
.

The following snippet of code for reference.

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      fieldVal: "Default Value",
    }
  }
  
  onUpdate = (val) => {
    this.setState({
      fieldVal: val,
    })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Parent</h2>
        Value in Parent Component State: {this.state.fieldVal}
        <br/>
        <Child passedVal={this.state.fieldVal} onUpdate={this.onUpdate} />
        <br />
        <OtherChild passedVal={this.state.fieldVal} onUpdate={this.onUpdate} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      fieldVal: props.passedVal,
    }
  }

  update = (e) => {
    this.props.onUpdate(e.target.value);
    this.setState({fieldVal: e.target.value});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Child</h4>
        <p>Value in Child: {this.state.fieldVal}</p>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="type here"
          onChange={this.update}
          value={this.state.fieldVal}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class OtherChild extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      fieldVal: this.props.passedVal,
    }
    
  }
  
  update = (e) => {
    this.props.onUpdate(e.target.value);
    this.setState({fieldVal: e.target.value});
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>OtherChild</h4>
        <p>Value in OtherChild: {this.state.fieldVal}</p>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="type here"
          onChange={this.update}
          value={this.state.fieldVal}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}


React.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>React Hello World w/ JSBin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="react_example"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: since both use `fieldVal`, that should cause them to re-render as is? the problem is that you bind to `this.state.value` and should be to the prop or you should listen for the prop change and update your state. eg `componentWillRecieveProps(newProps){ if (this.state.fieldValue !== newProps.passedVal) this.setState({fieldVal: newProps.passedVal}) }` - you should read up on controlled input vs not: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Comment: @DimitarChristoff Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently passing down `passedVal` to your children as an initial state and then changing the local state of your children individually. If you want the children to always have the same value then you don't need to keep a local state and instead you can just use the value passed through `props`.

You don't need to change anything in your `Parent`. But your children would like like this:

```
class Child extends React.Component {    
  update = (e) => {
    this.props.onUpdate(e.target.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Child</h4>
        <p>Value in Child: {this.state.fieldVal}</p>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="type here"
          onChange={this.update}
          value={this.props.passedVal}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In child and other child, donot use state. Instead only props would siffice in them :

Child

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.update = this.update.bind(this);
  }

  update = (e) => {
    this.props.onUpdate(e.target.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Child</h4>
        <p>Value in Child: {this.props.fieldVal}</p>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="type here"
          onChange={this.update}
          value={this.props.fieldVal}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and same goes for other child